# Bluetooth Programming with Windows Sockets - Device in range

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, bluetooth, winsock

I'm trying to use Windows Sockets to discover BT device in range. I'm using the this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article for that.

The code works and I'm getting devices info by call to **WSALookupServiceNext(...)**.

The device information is provided by the [WSAQUERYSETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct.

How do I know if the device is in range based on the data from the WSAQUERYSETW struct?

I can check if **WSAQUERYSETW::dwOutputFlags** is having one of the following flags:

```
BTHNS_RESULT_DEVICE_CONNECTED
BTHNS_RESULT_DEVICE_AUTHENTICATED
BTHNS_RESULT_DEVICE_REMEMBERED
```

And if device is CONNECTED, thus, it definitely in range, but what about other states?

What exactly REMEMBERED state is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those flags aren't mutually exclusive - a device may be all three or none.

- REMEMBERED means it is listed under 'bluetooth devices' in control panel. It may or may not be in range. The only guarantee we have with Remembered devices is that they were at some point in range in the past.
- AUTHENTICATED means it has been paired with the device - i.e. if a pin is needed, it has been supplied already. A device can be remembered but not authenticated; however any device that has been authenticated (i.e. windows has paired with it) will be remembered

If a device has been previously paired then removed manually, this un-authenticates it and it will be neither remembered nor authenticated.

Comment: Thanks! 
Follow up question, for discovering devices in range, should I set REMEMBERED flag to TRUE? Or can I set it to FALSE? From one hand, I don't want to reduce my results set, from other hand I don't want devices that are not in range in my result set.

Comment: Good question - I don't think you can, but if there's a way to get all in-range devices without either including remembered-but-not-in-range devices or excluding remembered-but-in-range devices, i would love to know.